# Insert Character on String Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I want to insert additional character on strings from "replace" function.

example

string = "AGAS Ranges" 
find = "gas"

my code

```
string.toLowerCase().replace("gas", `<b>${find}</b>`)
```

i want the result is like this, only add b and /b tag from the character you are looking for without changing the original words
`"A<b>GAS</b> Ranges"`

Thanks

Comment: [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace): _"The `replace()` method **returns a new string** with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match. If pattern is a string, only the first occurrence will be replaced. **The original string is left unchanged**."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can be a `RegExp`, so you can [reference to first matched group](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#capturing-groups-in-replacement) like `$1`.

`i` [modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) - makes the regex case insensitive.

```js
console.log("AGAS Ranges".replace(/(gas)/i, "<b>$1</b>"))
```

Use a variable in a regular expression:

```js
const string = 'AGAS Ranges';
const find = 'gas';
const regExp = new RegExp(`(${find})`, 'i');

console.log(string.replace(regExp, '<b>$1</b>'));
```

Comment: You can provide a bit of explanation of the solution too. It will be helpful .

Comment: hi thanks, but how to put variable inside the /(string)/i?

Comment: @RizalYogiPratama [How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)

Comment: @NikitaMadeev but if i using 

``
new RegExp(replace,"i")
``
 the "<b>$1</b>"
``
 is doesn't work